# How to prevent users from closing reward video ads

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, cordova-admob

I am using [admob google cordova plugin](https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova), and I am trying to prevent the user from closing the video before 30 seconds has passed. Is that possible with phonegap / cordova?

I only have the option to use:
`document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdClosed, function (e) {}, false);`
when the user is about to return to the application after clicking on an ad. But with this, the user still can press `X` and earn "points".

Is there any way to prevent the user from closing the window early, or to control the points if the video is not finished?

Comment: How about instead of preventing the user from closing a video he doesn't want (and for all we know didn't event know was going to happen), How about set a timer, and if it is closed prior to 30 seconds, just don't give the points!!  30-sec is an awful long time to lock a user out of their device!!  I disagree with the thought of some random programmer "owning" a user's device period, let alone for 30 sec and with no "cancel" option.  Users should still be able to retain full use of their device, and be able to change their mind. You could, however retain control of how/if points are awarded.

Comment: see "answers" below..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

You are not allowed to prevent a user from using their device. That would be more akin to a nasty virus.

What you need to do is set a timer.

**For example**:
Youtube ads cannot force you to watch an entire advertisement.
You can exit out.
But but the "reward" is locked behind watching (a portion of) the ad.
If the user *really* wants the content, or if the ad is short enough, or they like the ad, they will wait it out.
If not, they can cancel, but not view the "reward" content.
 - User retains full use of their device.
 - Developer is in control of the reward.

**In your case**:
 - Set a timer that starts when the user clicks on the ad.
 - Once 30sec has passed, reward the points if the ad window is still open.
 - If the window is closed in under 30sec, no points (or a small point).

To be fair to the user, you should show a timer so the user can see his "progress" toward the points goal, knows when his "required" time is up, and, in fact, has an indicator that you're (hopefully) keeping up your end of the deal.

---

(Re-posted from comment above):

How about instead of preventing the user from closing a video he doesn't want (and for all we know didn't event know was going to happen).
How about set a timer, and if it is closed prior to 30 seconds, just don't give the points!!

30-sec is an awful long time to lock a user out of their device!!
..Especially if the click was accidental!
..or the video plays volume, when they are in a quiet place (a meeting for instance),
..or an emergency arises.
..or they have to answer the phone,
..or..

I disagree with the thought of some random programmer "owning" a user's device period, let alone for 30 sec and with no "cancel" option.
Users should still be able to retain full use of their device, and be able to change their mind.

You could, however retain control of how/if points are awarded.

Comment: thank you! I was thinking about all that, but I didn't have idea what is the best option!  :)

Comment: Glad to help clarify and advise.  All the best on your project !

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off to not give "points" if `admob.events.onAdClosed` happened before 30 seconds from ad start. Some people do not need "points".